# Simplest way to cross table a sting based on its sign

Tags: r, dplyr, crosstab, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a sting, `x`, that I want to cross with itself, i.e. create a cross table, based on the value of said being either positive or negative (it’s never == 0).

i.e., say my data looks like this

```
foo <- tibble(x = c(-3L, 3L, -3L, 3L, -2L, 1L))
foo
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>       x
#>   <int>
#> 1    -3
#> 2     3
#> 3    -3
#> 4     3
#> 5    -2
#> 6     1
```

I’m trying something like this

```
with(foo, table(x, with(foo, x > 0)))
#> x    FALSE TRUE
#>   -3     2    0
#>   -2     1    0
#>   1      0    1
#>   3      0    2

library(dplyr) # install.packages(c("dplyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tidyr) # install.packages(c("tidyr"), dependencies = TRUE)
foo %>% 
group_by(sign(x) == 1) %>%
tally() %>%
spread(x, n, fill = 0)
```

but what I want is

```
neg <- unlist(subset(foo, x < 0))
pos <- unlist(subset(foo, x > 0))

# order `neg` 
neg <- factor(ordered(as.factor(neg)), levels=rev(levels(ordered(as.factor(neg)))))

table(neg, pos)
#>     pos
#> neg  1 3
#>   -2 1 0
#>   -3 0 2
```

any suggestions for a *simple* way to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, by splitting your variable according to its sign and then calling `table`:

**Edit:**

As stated by @eddi , in fact `table` can handle `list`s as input so you can just do:

```
with(foo, table(split(x, sign(x))))
#    1
#-1   1 3
#  -3 0 2
#  -2 1 0
```

If you need to have the levels ordered by absolute value, you can define each part of `x` ("for each sign") as a `factor` with ordered levels (according to absolute value),:

```
with(foo, table(lapply(split(x, sign(x)), 
                       function(sp_x) factor(sp_x, levels=unique(sp_x[order(abs(sp_x))]), ordered=TRUE))))

 #   1
#-1   1 3
#  -2 1 0
#  -3 0 2
```

---

**Old:**

```
do.call(table, split(foo$x, sign(foo$x))) 
# or with(foo, do.call(table, split(x, sign(x))))

#    1
#-1   1 3
#  -3 0 2
#  -2 1 0
```

Comment: what's the `do.call` for?

Comment: @eddi because split gives a list, would it work without?

Comment: @Cath, I like the `list` trick from @eddi. Any chance that could be sorted in a way such that the negative values start at `-2` (I also updated the question to reflect this).

Comment: @EricFail see my edit: you can define, for each sign of x, a factor with levels ordered according to absolute value.

Comment: @Cath, Excellent

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use `xtabs`. The output is (very) ugly but right.

```
xtabs(~ x[x > 0] + x[x < 0], data = foo)
#        x[x < 0]
#x[x > 0] -3 -2
#       1  0  1
#       3  2  0
```

**EDIT.**
Returning to the OP's original solution, the following works.

```
with(foo, table(pos = x[x > 0], neg = x[x < 0]))
#   neg
#pos -3 -2
#  1  0  1
#  3  2  0
```

Comment: I'm playing around trying to reduce the number of times I have to state the input variables, currently at `xtabs(with(foo,( ~ x[x > 0] + x[x < 0]),))`

Comment: `with(foo, xtabs())`... - Nice ans btw :)

Comment: @Sotos, right `with(foo, xtabs(~ x[x > 0] + x[x < 0], ))`

Comment: @Sotos I like the `data` argument. It makes the code more readable.

Comment: if you really want to reduce the number of times you have to state the input variables *in practice*, wrap this up as a helper function - then you just need `my_handy_function(foo)` ...

Comment: @BenBolker, good point. Thanks. I asked the question as I often find there's some handy R-function that already exist, but I don't know about it or don't know how to use it.

Comment: do you think my comment deserves to be an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Maybe. Formalize it and we'll see. It looks promising.

Comment: @BenBolker, I do too. Obviously. In particular if you could add a sort on absolute value as Cath did below (I also added an `# order `neg` 
` to my question  to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Deriving from your question:

```
> foo <- data.frame(x = c(-3L, 3L, -3L, 3L, -2L, 1L))
> 
> table(pos = foo[foo$x>0,],neg = foo[foo$x<0,])
   neg
pos -3 -2
  1  0  1
  3  2  0
>
```

Comment: Updated with the data.frame creation (didn't use tibble)

Comment: How is this different with what the OP did?

Comment: Thanks. It does the job. I do however still have to state the data, `foo`, four times, and the variable, `x`, two times. Would be need if there was less repetition.